# asia-south1-a - does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

i am facing this difficulty from last 2 days, and can not start VM.

"The zone 'projects/oceanic-trail-******/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."

Can someone provide any suggestion...

Comment: Talk to the support team of your provider.

Answer (score 1):

For the resource you are requesting, there is currently zero unallocated/available capacity in the the zone you selected for the launch, asia-south1-a.

> Try a different zone, or try again later.

Choose a different zone for launching your new VM, or verify (from documentation or by creating a support request) that the type of VM you want is actually available in asia-south1-a and then wait for a while longer and try again to see if capacity has become available.

Comment: I am waiting from last 2 days and kept trying to restart but failed every time. And can't more VM in terminated state in another zone.

Comment: You can move it manually by following https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Thank you...